I need to remove Ubuntu from an iMac
My MacBook display died. My dad has an old 2011 iMac sitting in his basement, so I was going to use it for an external display. He at some point tried to put Ubuntu on the iMac. It was apparently unsuccessful because it gets to a logo screen and then it just stalls out. He said he never could get it to pull up and just put it aside. Now I need to remove Ubuntu from this iMac, so I can reinstall macOS.
Here are some images I've taken along the way:








https://imgur.com/a/V7arXMQ

You don't remove an unwanted OS , you just install your wanted OS (and it will overwrite the existing OS).

Does this answer your question? How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on? What you want is the same as this, only you'll be installing MacOS instead of windows; Ubuntu is not involved in that process

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! - No, you will not get eaten alive here for asking a question. There is no need to uninstall Ubuntu, You simply install the operating system of your choice to overwrite any previously operating system.
